# Android Studio cannot find GCC for NDK compilation

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to get the demo app of LittleEndians SoundEffects Framework to run with AndroidStudio. They have a demo version for Android here:

https://www.littleendian.com/developers/free-trial/

Unfortunately this download is still made for Eclipse. After importing it to AndroidStudio you have to copy the files from the "include"-folder of the download to a "libs"-folder of the imported app.
Then change the includes of exampleAppEntryPoint.cpp from

```
  #include "le/utility/filesystem.hpp"
  #include "le/utility/trace.hpp"
```

to

```
  #include "../../../libs/le/utility/filesystem.hpp"
  #include "../../../libs/le/utility/trace.hpp"
```

Now the hpp-files are found and the app should be ready to build. But when I try to start the app I get the following error:

**D:...\app\libs\le\utility\abi.hpp
Error:(56, 10) error: #error LE SDKs require GCC 4.7+ or Clang 3.2+ with enabled C++11 support (-std=c++11)**

I installed the newest version of cygwin and I can run "g++ --version" from the cygwin shell, but AndroidStudio somehow does not know how to find gcc.
In the project settings there is an entry that points to the ndk-bundle folder.

This is my first attempt to use the NDK, so maybe it's a simple config thing...idk

Comment: That's a compilation error from a `#error` pragma so a GCC/Clang version is being found and used, check its version and the compilation switches passed to it. Also check the code round about the #error line referenced above for the test producing the error, it might be too specific.

Comment: Okay thanks so far! Do you know how I can check which version AndroidStudio is using? I have the ndk build r10e (64-bit) installed, but I can't find any gcc.exe or similar within the ndk-build folder.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is that the Android NDK does not support C++11 features by default. But I tried several combinatinos of LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11, -std=c++11 and so on without success. I also changed the NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION to different values (clang, clang3.6, 4.8 and 4.9) to no avail. Any suggestinos?

Comment: Android Studio project is included in the demo trial as of version 3.1.0: https://www.littleendian.com/developers/free-trial/.